# Swift UILabel Subview not updating

Tags: ios, swift

I have a header of a UICollectionView. This header contains a UILabel. I'm updating the text value of the label by calling a function updateClue through a delegate.

```
class LetterTileHeader: UICollectionViewCell {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  var clueLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.text = "HELLO"
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
  }()

  func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = GlobalConstants.colorDarkBlue
    addSubview(clueLabel)

    clueLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    clueLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    clueLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    clueLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  func updateClue(clue: String) {
    clueLabel.text = clue
    debugLabel()
  }

  func debugLabel() {
    print(clueLabel.text)
  }
```

The function debugLabel is printing with the changed text coming from updateClue. But the label on the screen does not update. What am I missing? I've tried using a DispatchQueue.main.async block with changing the label text within that but no still no change.

UpdateClue function is triggered from another class via a Protocol Delegation.

```
extension PuzzleViewController: WordTileDelegate {
  func relaySelectedWordId(wordId: String!) {
    selectableTiles.updateTileHeaderClue(wordId: wordId)
  }
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I've figured out what's going on. This subview is created each time I select a new cell. Looking into why that's happening. Will update soon.

The issue I'm having is due to this cell class being initialized multiple times. I believe the label I'm seeing is not the current one being updated, but the previous label that was instantiated. I have a new issue though which I may open a question on if I can't figure it out.

Comment: when you change the label headerview of the collection is visible or you scroll to it and find it still not changed ?

Comment: I see the label saying Hello in the header, but it doesn't update. By design I have only one header, and the collection is limited so does not scroll.

Comment: The issue is the label does not update when calling updateClue, but debugLabel does return the updated text. It's the label in the header that just isn't updating its text as expected.

Comment: you use autolayout to place the label ? label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false ?

Comment: Not using autoLayout, no Storyboard. Programmatically only.

Comment: where do you call that function

Comment: I've updated the main post. Also see my comments further down to Lamar.

Answer (score 0):

You have two UILabels and/or two LetterTileHeaders. The one you are updating is *not* the one that is being displayed on the screen.

One way to prove this is to put a breakpoint on the line after `let label = UILabel()`. It is very likely that the breakpoint will be hit more than once.

Another way would be to look at the screen layout in the debugger and find the memory location of the UILabel that is getting displayed, then put a breakpoint in the `updateClue` method and compare that label's memory location to the one that is being displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Follow code seems to be wrong, this mean each time when you use clueLble it will give you fresh UILable instance.

```
var clueLabel: UILabel = {
let label = UILabel()
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
label.text = "HELLO"
label.textColor = UIColor.white
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return label
```

}()

Try doing this :

1. just replace above code with 
   `var clueLabel = UILabel()`
2. Add following func:

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
   label.text = "HELLO"
   label.textColor = UIColor.white
   label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   backgroundColor = GlobalConstants.colorDarkBlue
   addSubview(clueLabel)

   clueLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
   clueLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
   clueLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
   clueLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
   ```

   }
3. remove `setupViews()`